# Using Zwoptex - Getting a Plist

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, plist, sprite

I want to create a plist from a SpriteSheet using Zwoptex, I've got the spriteSheet(1 Png file with all the sprites I need) and I would like the Plist to be showed as If there were many frames. (I dragged a sprite sheet with  3x4 sprites in it) but I don't have the individual sprites to drag them, do you by any chance know any program that will cut the spritesheet for me to drag them into Zwoptex or is there a way that Zwoptex can Identify each sprite in the sheet? And get the frames like this

- Frames

  - HumanUp1

    - ...etc
  - HumanUp2

    - ...etc
  - HumanUp3..etc etc

    - ...etc
- MetaData

instead of

- Frames

  - HumanWalkSpriteSheet
         * ...etc
- MetaData

  - etc...

Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 1):

[AlfredSpriteUnlocker](http://www.alferdspritesheetunpacker.forkandbeard.co.uk/forkandBeard/apps/AlferdSpritesheetUnpacker/Download.aspx) can help you extract images from your spritesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is tool: SpriteSheet-Unpacker

This works for png sheet. For pvr, just open source and change .png to .pvr

https://github.com/gongpengjun/SpriteSheet-Unpacker

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the sprites from png then import those sprites to Zwoptex.
I can recommend this software for your problem, but first I would suggest to check video of this software and then go for it.

Softwares: https://store.bluegamerzstudio.com/downloads/spooky-spritesheet-extractor-and-merger/